# Android how to get int type in JSONObject

Tags: java, android, json, integer

I have an issue with putting `int` in JSON. I have an integer where I need to save the error code which server returns me. The problem is that I have to parse it in `JSONObject`, but `JSONObject` takes only Strings, not integers. Here is an example what I'm trying to do:

```
int errorCode;
JSONObject ErrorCode;
ErrorCode = new JSONObject(errorCode);
```

Any suggestions how to solve that issue?

Comment: Are you trying to put an `int` _into_ JSON, or parse an `int` _from_ JSON?

Comment: I need to put an int in JSONObject.

Comment: Could you clarify your question? You mention parsing but in your code sample you're creating a new JSONObject.

Comment: Actually I'm not really sure if this is the right way...The idea is that I'm using an integer where to save the error code which server sends me so I can do something depends on the returned code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can do this ; when you try to create your json object , use this :

```
//method 1
String myJson = " {errorCode:"+errorCode+"}";
ErrorCode = new JSONObject(myJson);

//method 2
ErrorCode = new JSONObject();
ErrorCode.put("errorCode", errorCode);// jsonObject.put(String key,Object value);
```

and then when you try to parse it , you can use :

```
json.getInt(String key); // in this case, the key is : errorCode
```

Answer (score 7):

`JSONObject` is the code equivalent to a json text-response. It's not a single key of that response. What you most likely want to do is read a single key thats contained in the servers response. For that, use [`JSONObject.getInt("key")`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#getInt%28java.lang.String%29).

*Sample:*

```
int errorCode;
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(serverResponseString);
errorCode = json.getInt("error_key");
```

If you want to compose a `JSONObject` instead of parsing one, use `JSONObject.put()`.

```
int errorCode = 42;
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("error_key", errorCode);
String jsonString = json.toString();
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a new `JSONObject`, then on that `JSONObject` call `put("fieldName", intValue)`. See [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#put%28java.lang.String,%20int%29).

Answer (score 1):

JSONObject have a public JSONObject(java.lang.Object bean) constructor. Try to create ErrorCode object with code field and pass it to  JSONObject constructor.